# Application crashing on Intune fully managed Android devices

Tags: android, microsoft-intune, mdm, crash, endpoint

We have Android phones on which we need to enroll in Intune as fully managed company owned devices.

We have a custom application installed in the device, however after installation the application is crashing on some of the devices.

The same application works fine with the devices which are not enrolled in Intune and other models.

A support ticket has been opened with Microsoft. It would be great if anybody could help.

Comment: I'd start by debugging the application on those devices.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, actually the issue was with the application itself as it was not working with android 11,